# type error : cannot read property error

Tags: node.js, protractor

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var wb = new Excel.Workbook();
wb.xlsx.readFile(' Clean Up 0517 updated.xls').then(function (data) {
var worksheet = wb.getWorksheet('Report');

 for(var v=0;v<worksheet.rowCount;v++)
    {
        var lN = worksheet.getCell("B"+v).value;
        console.log(" V :"+v+"------ Name :" +lN);
    }

  })
```

Can someone please help me over this, struggling with it for the last 2 days
getting the following error:  Cannot read property 'rowCount' of undefined

I have to loop through an xls file and get the values for each column and perform some validations on them.

Comment: you should check if `worksheet` even contains anything since the error states `rowCount` is undefined. Also, try removing the space `' Clean`.

Comment: I am able to get  a single value from the worksheet if i give the single cell address but not anything else. There is no space between them in the code. If i console.log(worksheet) I get all the records